# Uploading multiple files with Flask

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

Is there a way to receive multiple uploaded files with Flask? I've tried the following:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
  <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="">
  <input type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

And then printed the contents of `request.files['file']`:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
  if not _upload_dir:
    raise ValueError('Uploads are disabled.')

  uploaded_file = flask.request.files['file']
  print uploaded_file
  media.add_for_upload(uploaded_file, _upload_dir)
  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('_main'))
```

If I upload multiple files, it only prints the first file in the set:

```
<FileStorage: u'test_file.mp3' ('audio/mp3')>
```

Is there a way to receive multiple files using Flask's built-in upload handling? Thanks for any help!

Comment: One can skip brackets in "file[]", name="file" is ok to use.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use method [getlist](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) of [flask.request.files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.files), for example:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    uploaded_files = flask.request.files.getlist("file[]")
    print uploaded_files
    return ""
```

Comment: I tried this but it says 'flask' is not defined. where am I going wrong? what are the modules I need to import?

Comment: from flask import request

Comment: request.files.getlist("file[]")

Comment: the square brackets are not a must.

Comment: Doesn't work without square brackets for me on Flask 0.12.2

Comment: no [] worked for me. Otherwise I was just getting an empty list

Comment: With Flask 1.0.2 I was getting an empty list with square brackets included, and correct file list when not included.

Comment: In addition to the answer, one would test this using curl -X POST -F "file[]=@/path/to/file1" -F "file[]=@/path/to/file2" ... srvaddr/upload

Comment: This worked for me `request.files.getlist("images")`. and also I needed to get form then I used `request.form.getlist("data")`. Working both!

Comment: The key you use for `getlist` has to match the `name` of the `input` element in your HTML.  That’s all.

Answer (score 31):

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        files = flask.request.files.getlist("file")
        for file in files:
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
```

It works for me.

for UPLOAD_FOLDER if you need add this just after app = flask.Flask(**name**)

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/upload'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 16):

Using Flask 1.0.2+:

```
files = request.files.getlist("images")
```

Where `images` is the key of the key/value pair. With the Value being the multiple images.

Comment: Thanks! And as it may help others prevent some searching, note that `file.filename` gives the name of the file for each `file` in `files`.

Answer (score 8):

this is a working solution for flask version '1.0.2':

```
images = request.files.to_dict() #convert multidict to dict
for image in images:     #image will be the key 
    print(images[image])        #this line will print value for the image key
    file_name = images[image].filename
    images[image].save(some_destination)
```

basically, images[image] has an image file with save function added to it
Now do whatever you like to do with the data.

Comment: to_dict doesn't get list of image.

Comment: @TomSawyer Which flask version are you using? can you put 
     print(type(request.files))
 in your code and see what is the type of request.files. If it is multidict then to_dict method should give you a dictionary object in return.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre This is a workig solution for flask 2.0.1 too, but `to_dict` doesn't seem to the the whole list of files when I use `FormData` in JS. It only fetches the first file, Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: @collinsmarra before the for loop print the images and see what you are getting I am using this code in many projects and it returns me one file or more that one file based on what i send from client side. If possible check the code on your client side JS. You might find a clue there.