# Files uploads with curl in Flask

Tags: linux, web-services, curl, flask, upload

I must upload file to flask via curl command. I tried sending using the curl commands from [Folder/Files Upload with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898283/folder-files-upload-with-flask) and it failed to identify the request.

```
curl --form "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://hostname/resource
```

And the Python code:

```py
from flask import Flask,abort,render_template,request,redirect,url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER 


@app.route('/upload/',methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method =='POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        print request.files
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The data should be saved upon POSTing via CURL command

Comment: *"failed to identify the request"* is not a good problem statement. Please provide the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well you probably need to return something, without it Flask gives you error try to add

```
return jsonify({'message':'File uploaded!'})
```

after that and try it :) Remember to import jsonify from flask!

Comment: Also im not sure about your curl request, shouldnt be like this?
curl -X POST \
  http://hostname/resource \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data \
  -F fileupload=@filename.txt