# Can't submit multiple input files in flask+html

Tags: python, html, flask, read-data

I am trying to upload multiple files using HTML into my flask application. I have used an html form below

```html
<form action="url", method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <font size="2">
        File2: <input type=file name=file1><br/>
        File1: <input type=file name=file2><br/>
      </font>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

and the files are being read in an Flask package as

```
@app.route('/process_data', methods=["POST"])
def process_data():
    print request.files
```

when I tested this and I only upload a single file this runs fine but when I upload both the files I can see that the request.files field is empty.

I is not possible to upload multiple files into flask from one form ?

Comment: Check this answer, it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065157/8882687

Answer (score 1):

You have to use, [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist)

```
@app.route('/process_data', methods=["POST"])
def process_data():
   uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
   print uploaded_files
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, this works but now I can see inconsistent behavior sometime the uploaded_files variable has the files fed while other times its just blank . Can get hold of the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `request.files` is not empty, it will be `ImmutableMultiDict` like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('file1', <FileStorage: 'test1.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>),  ('file2', <FileStorage: 'test222.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')>)])
```

You can convert it to dictionary with :

```
dict(request.files)
```

Then it will be:

```
{'file1': [<FileStorage: 'test1.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>], 'file2': [<FileStorage: 'test222.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')>]}
```

Then you can access the `file1` and `file2` from here.

If you want to upload multiple files, suggest this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817182/uploading-multiple-files-with-flask) will be more clear for you, but you have to change your html with:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="">
```