# Reading multiple files using Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to read multiple images uploaded by the user through HTML page. I am not sure, how the multiple files are handled. I presumed that, the files can be handled as an index but it went wrong. Please find the HTML code below:

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p><input type=file name="newname" multiple>
     <input type=submit value=License name=submit_button>
</form>
```

My python code below that I tried:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    blob=file[0].read()
```

The error I received is :

```
TypeError: 'FileStorage' object does not support indexing
```

Please help me in doing this

Thank you in advance

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask/20017830#20017830)

Comment: Hi @pyd..thank you for your response. I am not getting one thing. I am already using file.read(). How can I use it when I get multiple files from the user ? 3 images uploaded and I have to use every single image and process it

Comment: I think `flask.request.files.getlist("file[]")` check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817182/uploading-multiple-files-with-flask#11817318)